# How to do 'Wait and Answer to System' with Perl

Tags: perl, shell

I am writing a Perl that automatically interacts with another script.
The script needs double confirm for some critical operations.

Executing the script without Perl is something like the following:

```
$ ./TheScript
TheScript Starting.......
Following step might be harmful to your system.
Are You Sure (Y/N)?
$ Y
TheScript finished!
```

Now I want a Perl script doing that for me.
I am sure that (Y/N) confirmation will exist within 10 sec. So I've tried:

```
system('./TheScript');
sleep 10;
system('Y');
```

This failed because it stuck in system('./TheScript') and did not
 go to the rest of the script including reply 'Y'.

Backstick ` is almost the same as system except it captures the STDOUT.
exec() is more impossible because it forks TheScript and is not able to do anything on it again.

Did I make any mistakes doing the analysis? Or are there any functions doing what I want?

Comment: You might want to look at the [expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand the [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) function.  It waits for the program to exit before your Perl program continues.

To drive an interactive program from Perl, you want the [Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect) module (or perhaps [Expect::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect::Simple)).  However, for a very simple case like you're suggesting, [IPC::Open2](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open2) may suffice, and it's a core module.

Comment: It not feasible for me using 3rd party modules because my company's security policy. The standard module Open2 works for me. Thank you!

Comment: @PeterHsu: That is a very strange security policy. All of the core Perl modules, and Perl itself are "third party". As is Linux.

Answer (score 0):

As per your written Perl script, you are facing issue when double confirmation occurred by the system. So for that I can suggest,  you can write the script in such way that ,

first it checks first confirmation OK fine
if next again it asks confirmation , your script must check second confirmation as well

for this ,

my $conf= "Are You Sure (Y/N)?"; my $length = $conf;  if ($length > 0) { sleep 0; system('Y'); } else { system('N'); }

I hope , this script will be fine for you.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't really understand. But my problem with system will be "not able to leave TheScript" because TheScript kept wait my confirmation.